# In a Spring Repository Query Method, is it possible to enforce presence / that a parameter be required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

i.e. In he following query method in a spring repository neither a nor b are required from an HTTP request. Is it possible to enforce the presence of these parameters at the repository level?

I would like to be explicit with the API I expose to the client. Right now no params, a, b, a&b are all accepted by the exposed endpoint. However I only want to expose a&b.

```
List<Thing> findByBAndC(@Param(value="a") Long a,@Param(value="b") Long b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any Spring Data way to do it, but spontanously I can think of some ways...

You could use a custom @Query where only if both are present ( "is not null" ) something would be returned, if that's enough

You could also (ab)use security with @PreAuthorize to check if both parameters are not null, but that sounds smelly.

Probably the most easy (and least smelly) way I can think of is to write your own `Aspect` that wraps around the method and throws an exception of both parameters are not present... For example, create your own custom annotation, put it before your method and then write an aspect, something like (not tested):

```
@Around("@annotation(com.example.AllParametersRequired.class)")
public Object throwExceptionOnMissingParameters(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
      int nullCount = Arrays.stream(pjp.getArgs()).filter( o -> o == null).count();
      if (nullCount > 0) throw new RuntimeException("Null is not allowed.);
      return pjp.proceed();
}
```

You will probably have to experiment there a little bit, to see which pointcut is the best for your case, but I don't see why you shouldn't be able to wrap an aspect around Spring Data's repository methods. Anyway, here's a link to the Spring AOP documentation, which will probably be helpful if you want to go that way: [Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)